# apache .htaccess not redirecting to https in subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS in my .htaccess which is inside a subfolder which passes all the requests to my index.php file which is responsible for Routing.
But I is not getting redirected to HTTPS version of the website in my subfolder. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, my root .htaccess is configured properly but I'm confused about the subfolder .htaccess... 
Everything works fine when HTTP in subfolder..
And also on root level it works fine too, I'm getting redirected to HTTPS but not when I go to the subfolder.

This is my root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And this is my subfolder .htaccess:

```
# This will pass the requests to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /SomeFolder
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)https://$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And also ZnVjayBTdGFja292ZXJmbG93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoobWithGuns,

I think I can help you solve your problem but first I have a few questions.
1)Are you using virtual hosts? And if so, are there different virtual hosts (conf files) for each directory?
2)Is there an explicit reason why you are using https in the sub-directory and not the root? Or would you be able to use https all around?

Comment: I think you haven't got my question mate

Comment: root level redirects to HTTPS, but subfolder doesn't

Comment: Also, yes I am using XAMPP on Linux and obviously there is the vhosts file of course.

Comment: Oh, I see. I apologize I don't think I understood your question first time around. You can use "RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
# This checks to see if the connection is http.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location to the same location but using HTTPS if they attempt http."

Comment: You can also set a hsts header in your apache security.conf file. "Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains". This will force https over the root and any subdomains.

Comment: Alright, but I don't think that will make any difference... Its just the same thing but I do it by checking if HTTPS is not on, and you want me to do it by checking if its port 80 or 443... Same thing huh?

Comment: Let me know if that works. Your best bet may just be enabling hsts